# Why condition is met?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

It should be a super basic question, but I can't scratch my head around it:

```
  "Parameters" : {
      "SNSTopicName" : {
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "MyTopic"
      },
      "SubscriptionEmail" : {
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "na"
      }
  },
  "Conditions" : {
    "SubscriptionProvided": {
      "Fn::Not" : [{
        "Fn::Equals" : [
          {"Ref" : "SubscriptionEmail"},
          "na"
        ]
      }]
    }
  }
```

But if I don't change the default value of SubscriptionEmail ("na"), the template starts to be deployed and fails because of the incorrect email format.
Would appreacite an idea of how to ensure that deployments starts only when default value has changed?

Comment: *But if I don't change the default value of SubscriptionEmail ("na"), the template starts to be deployed and fails because of the incorrect email format.* so it's behaving exactly as you intended? the problem is that the default value obviously is not a valid email

Comment: i just don't want deployment to even start when the default 'na' is used - this way I'm kind of trying to force users to change it to hopefully a valid email

Comment: Is this not how conditions work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AllowedPattern property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) on your parameter to ensure that the template is not launched until a valid value is prompted.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like a better option for me. It is though a bit weird that AllowedPattern is applied even to the default value :) So if I use a pattern for en email address, my default 'na' ends up with an error without possibility to change it

Comment: Unfortunately yes, even the default parameter must be compliant with the allowed pattern :)